# R - replace values conditionally when column names are similar

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have a large dataframe df with 41 columns of data. The first 40 columns have all similar variable names TD1, TD2, TD3 .... TD40 that contain characters. The last column is Catflag whose value is dependent on the codes contained within the other 40 columns of data.

Here is a small subset of the dataframe.

TD1   TD2    TD3 ...... TD40    Catflag
1345  4673  3908        2348     Stroke
4721  9854  5732        O763     Diabetes
5739  6894  3957        5864     Cardiac
967D  6046  1345        4T67     Stroke
...........

What I would like to do is for R to look through each row and if finds either codes (5984, 6046, 3331) anywhere in the 40 columns of data (T1-T40) it will change/replace the value in Catflag for that row to "Surgery". If it doesn't find either of the 3 values then the Catflag value for that row remains unchanged. Therefore in the dataframe above only the 4th row would change from "Stroke" to "Surgery"

I used the following R code to do the job

rowwise()%>%
df$Catflag[any(c_across(starts_with("TD")) %in% c("5984", "6046", "3331"))] <- "Surgery"

It didn't work and got  "invalid (NULL) left side of assignment" error message.
Tried slight changes and variations to the command to no avail.

The above command works on multiple conditions such as this example:
df$Catflag[(df$TD1 == "3331") & (df$TD4 == "7856")] <- "Emergency"

Just dont know how to make it work for applying the same condition over 40 columns???

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `lapply` like below :

```
values_to_check <- c(5984, 6046, 3331)
cols <- grep('TD', names(df))

df$Catflag[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[cols], `%in%`, values_to_check))] <- 'Surgery'
```

and with `dplyr` `rowwise` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Catflag = if(any(c_across(starts_with('TD')) %in% values_to_check)) 
                   'Surgery' else Catflag)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak. What would be an option if you didn't know column numbers of the TD1-TD40? For example those 40 columns were part of a very large dataframe that had hundreds of columns of data and you had to use the column name?

Comment: @dapdot1 `dplyr` answer should work for that. I updated the base R answer.

Comment: That seems to work. One question - when you use the mutate function in your answer, does that mean R will write over the original Catflag column of data? I have always associated mutate function as adding an extra column of data to the dataframe. My confusion - that's why i never thought of using it for this problem. Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes `mutate` creates a new column or overwrites existing column if it is present. So when none of the `values_to_check` values are present in the row it will return the same `Catflag` value.

Comment: Can i ask one small variation to the original question. What if values_to_check  vector wasn't a known set of values i.e values_to_check <- c(5984, 6046, 3331) but was based upon only on the first three characters of each value in each row of the 40 TD columns. So if any of the 40 TD columns started with  "598" then  then Category  value becomes Surgery. I've tried to incorporate the Substr or grepl functions as solutions but not sure how to go about it. Any ideas??

Comment: I think for this it would be better to ask a new question with a relevant example.